# How can I properly use the Fork/Join framework without an IndexOutOfRangeException?

Tags: java, exception, fork-join

I am creating a desktop app that reads files for certain things in a fast time and I have decided to use the Fork/Join framework(there is no turning back now anyways). However I am getting an IndexOutOfRange exception, when performing the actions on the ArrayList<>. It worked well the last time I did it, the only difference is that that Time I was using a normal array. I really am baffled on why it is not working so please help me out

RESOURCES:
Code:

```
@Override
protected void compute() {
    List<FileInformation> informationList =
            new ArrayList<>();
    // If the number of elements is lower than the threshold
    // then compute() will process sequentially
    if((end - start) < seqThreshold){
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++){
            informationList.add(
                    searcher.search(
                            searcher.strip(list
                                    .get(i)))
            );
        }
        information = information.addAll(
                informationList
        );
    }
    yelse{
        int middle = (start + end) / 2;

        invokeAll(new FileTask(file, start, middle),
                new FileTask(file, middle, end));
    }
}
```

Stack Trace: ActionCommands:80 just invokes the task

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:603)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:678)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:722)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.invoke(ForkJoinPool.java:2432)
    at gui.actions.ActionCommands$6.actionPerformed(ActionCommands.java:80)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Button.java:411)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Button.processEvent(Button.java:379)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 7 out of bounds for length 7
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:426)
    at filecomputations.FileTask.compute(FileTask.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:189)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1665)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1598)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
```

Comment: Have you checked `Index 7 out of bounds for length 7` in `FileTask` at 47?

Comment: @akuzminykh Yes, of course I did. Its .get(i) which means the i is exceeding the bounds